# IIS reverse proxy redirection rule

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I have a treadmill whose display is hard-wired to https://matrixfitness.com/ch/deu and there is no way to change it. However, I need it to point to http://10.10.10.16:3777 (internal IIS server).

As a hack, I have created a DNS zone "matrixfitness.com" within my LAN pointing the internal server, and that works just fine. However, I am unable to create the correct IIS reverse-proxy rule that redirects to the correct address and port. Might a good soul help me? I am going crazy over this...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm understanding you right, but you can try this as the web.config for the site you've created in IIS.  I'm assuming you have a site in IIS created that you're trying to make redirect to matrixfitness?  I use something similar for Plex, to redirect an external URL to an internal one, so I've modified that for you, but I'm not sure if it'll work or not of course.  If your IIS site is the 10.10.10.16:3777 then you can change the match url's to (.*) instead of 10.10...

I'm also not sure if it'll work with having the port specified in the match url (:3777).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="10.10.10.16:3777" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://matrixfitness.com/ch/deu" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="10.10.10.16:3777" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://matrixfitness.com/ch/deu/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you! Actually I wanted to accomplish the opposite: redirecting matrixfitness 443 (Https) to the internal http 10.10.10.16 port 3777. But either way, it says that the "rule backreference 1 is not valid".